# Disable/enable form validation on certain action in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, validation

I have to action: A and B. I want to toggle form validation on with action B but not A.

How would I do that with AngularJS?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this can be done using [`ng-non-bindable`](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/docs/api/ng/directive/ngNonBindable).

```
<!-- Use it with form -->
<form name="myForm" ng-non-bindable>

<!-- Use it with element -->
<input type="text" name="textfield" ng-non-bindable>
```

Comment: I read the document but i haven't got any idea how to apply it to this case? From what i understand `ng-non-bindable` just ignore whatever inside the DOM element. Do u have a working example?